# How to grep 'Advertised link modes" from ethtool command?

Tags: linux, grep

How to get only these values `10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 1000baseT/Full` from this command?

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
```

I've tried something like this `sudo ethtool eth0 | grep 'Advertised link modes:' | cut -d " " -f5-6` but it's not working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
# ethtool enp1s0 | sed -ne '/Supported link modes:/,/:/p' | sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e '$d'
10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
1000baseT/Full
```

The first sed prints everything from the "Supported link modes" line up and including the next line with a colon. The second one removes that last line (it's the "Supported pause frame use" or something), the label on first one and the whitespace. Looking at the next line with a colon makes it work regardless of how many lines the list is split on, and regardless of what the next field actually is.